# Laravel: Login form "Remember Me" functionality not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, remember-me

One of my website is developed in Laravel, it was working fine before. What does is I want to move website from beta.example.com to example.com so I have pointed to beta with original domain name(example.com).

The Website is working fine but all remember me functionality is not working. Now Users have to enter the password and also if they check the check box (remember me) still it does not store the password in cookies or session.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Remember me does not work by storing the password in cookies or in the session. This is achieved by using a remember_me cookie that stores a token that matches with the remember_me field in the `users` table. Did you configure the new url in your `.env` file?

Comment: Hi, Yes .env file has already set with new UrL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Add remember_token column in your users table - this is where the token will be stored.

2) Pass true as a second parameter of Auth::attempt() to enable remember me behaviour.

If you do this, Laravel will generate a token that will be saved in users table and in a cookie.

On subsequent requests, even if session cookie is not available, user will be authenticated automatically as long as remember-me cookie is there.